# Transitive action on a flag manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces, twistor-theory

Given a 4-dimensional complex space $T$, we consider the flag manifolds $F_{d_1,\ldots,d_m}(T)=\{(S_1,\ldots,S_m)\ |\ \textrm{dim}S_i=d_i, \ \ S_1\subset S_2\subset\ldots\subset S_m\}$. The $S_i$ are subspaces of $T$. My question is: how/why we can see that the action of the group $SL(4,\mathbb{C})$ over the flag is transitive, i.e, we can always find a $g\in SL(4,\mathbb{C}$ such thay for every two $[S_1,\ldots,S_m],[S_1',\ldots,S_m']$ we have that $g(S_1)=S_1',\ldots,g(S_m)=S_m'$.

And also, why we don't have one transitive action when we consider the group $SU(2,2)$?

Comment: Doesn't this just follow from choosing the right bases? Let $v_1,...,v_4$ and $v_1',..,v_4'$ be bases of $T$ such that $\langle v_1,...,v_k \rangle = S_k$ and $\langle v_1',...,v_\ell' \rangle = S_\ell'$. Now take the corresponding change of basis matrix $M$, and let $g = \frac{1}{\det M} M$.

Comment: Oops, missed the second part. Is $SU(2,2)$ a group consisting of $4\times 4$ block diagonal matrices $\left(\matrix{A & 0 \\ 0 & B}\right)$ with $A,B \in U(2)$? Assuming this is the case, the point is that while the $A$-blocks act transitively on the subspace spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ and similarly for the $B$-blocks and the latter two basis vectors, there is no way to, for instance, interchange $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$ and $\langle v_3,v_4\rangle$ via such matrices.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Which would be the form of the matrix to satisfies the condition of the question, i.e., how can I choose the matrix to act transitively over every subspace?

Comment: Sorry? Which part of my first comment is confusing? I've given you a recipe to carry any given flag into any other given flag, and to then reduce that to a matrix in $SL(4)$.

Comment: In the book that I'm reading says "this is a case of extension of basis and normalization", I understand  that I have to use the basis and that I have to multiplicate the matriz with the inverse of the determinant of the matrix,  but I still don't see how this action works. I have a $4\times4$ matrix acting over a $4\times 1$ vector, the same matrix acts over a $4\times2$ matrix and so on. In every step has to change the subspaces (yes, a change of basis) but I still don't see how I have to take this matrix to do that.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. Do you not see how this recipe takes $S_1$ to $S_1'$, $S_2$ to $S_2'$, and so on? Do you not see why this works for any pair of flags? Do you not see why normalizing to get a matrix in $SL(4)$ preserves what this does on the level of subspaces hence flags?

Comment: To be more specific, I want to see, explicitly, how to take the matrix $g$.

Comment: OK, choose coordinates so that $S_1$ is the span of $e_1 = \langle 1,0,0,0\rangle$, $S_2$ is the span of $e_1$ and $e_2 = \langle 0,1,0,0\rangle$, and so on. Now chose a basis $v_1,...,v_4$ so that the span of $v_1,...,v_k$ is $S_k'$. Then there are complex numbers $a_{ij}$ so that $v_j = \sum_{i=1}^4 a_{ij} e_i$. If $A = (a_{ij}) \in GL(4,\mathbb C)$, then $\frac{1}{\det A} A \in SL(4,\mathbb C)$, and this is our matrix.